# How do i remove anything starting with a '?' after trailing slash?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rule in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ product.php?var1=$1
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)?/?$ product.php?var1=$1&var2=$2
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)?/?([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)?/?$ product?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3
```

This is examples of urls used on my site::

```
/electronics/
/electronics/laptops/
/electronics/laptops/hp/
```

To avoid duplicate content, i am trying to eliminate anyone using these urls:

```
/electronics/?
/electronics/?qweqwe=fff
/electronics/laptops/?
/electronics/laptops/?q34t5gt=12
/electronics/laptops/hp/?
/electronics/laptops/hp/?id=12&hdhdhdhhd=3333
```

How can i make a 301-redirect (assumes this is the best way to avoid duplicate content), to remove anything starting with a '?' after a trailing slash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a lot of searching and testing. I came up with this solution:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^?#\ ]*)\?[^\ ]*\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301]
```